# JAXB Locator - missing dependency?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

On my current project we generate JAXB beans from an XSD file.
We need line number information on the beans (beyond XSD validation errors!) so I used the -Xlocator option specified here:

http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/jaxb/xjc.html

However, I'm missing the Locator class. The jar file referenced to on that six-year old page can't be found anywhere, as I don't see a download for JWSDP on any site at all.

Is XJC dead? Should I be using something else?

Edit: solution has to use Java 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, or at least part of it. XJC generates imports to the "internal" package versions of XmlLocation and Locatable. Don't ask me why!

I wrote a little script to replace these imports with the correct ones, and it seems to work fine now.

Comment: I create an issue in Java board because it's still exist in JAVA 1.8.
https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-1125

Answer (score 3):

XJC is far from dead, but that page you're referencing is ancient, and applies to JAXB 1. Java6 contains JAXB 2.1 (see the docs [here](http://jaxb.java.net/)). It's annoying that when you do a google search today, most of the hits you get back are for obsolete JAXB 1 references.

I'm not sure what you're requirements are. What do you mean by "We need line number information on the beans"?

edit: You mentioned the `@XmlLocation` annotation. This is a non-standard annotation within both Java6 and the JAXB reference implementation, which you'll be using with Java5. The classname is `com.sun.xml.bind.annotation.XmlLocation`, and the javadoc is [here](http://fisheye5.cenqua.com/browse/~raw,r=1.599/jaxb-architecture-document/www/doc/com/sun/xml/bind/annotation/XmlLocation.html). The reference implementation you can get from [here](http://jaxb.java.net/), if you don't have it already.

Comment: I want each bean to track where it came from in the XML file, i.e. the line and column numbers (line would be sufficient though).

It appears as if XJC supports this (through -Xlocator) and JAXB seems to do so with the @XmlLocation annotation, but I can't get it to work without that dependency.

If it's relevant: we're using java 1.5.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum, but ... maybe I'm stupid, but I can't find a proper download on that site. I can download a jar with a single ten megabyte class in it, but that's of little use to me. Where could I download the correct jar?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. I downloaded the *jaxb-impl.jar* since the the jaxb-api.jar is already included in Java 6 API. Just in case someone else needs a linux script to replace the wrong imports, as mentioned by Wouter.

Navigate to your project path and adjust `com.abc.generated` and `abc.xsd`.

```
#!/bin/sh
xjc -d src/ -p com.abc.generated -Xlocator abc.xsd

FILES=$(find src/ -type f -name *.java)
for f in $FILES
do
    sed -i 's/\(.*import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.Locatable;.*\)/import com.sun.xml.bind.Locatable;/g' $f
    sed -i 's/\(.*import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.annotation.XmlLocation;.*\)/import com.sun.xml.bind.annotation.XmlLocation;/g' $f
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For Maven-User add the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

and replace the imports

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.Locatable;
import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.annotation.XmlLocation;
```

with

```
import com.sun.xml.bind.Locatable;
import com.sun.xml.bind.annotation.XmlLocation;
```